# $setPristine() method in Angular 1.2.1 doesn't appear to work as intended

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have am trying to reset a textbox using the `$setPristine` function in AngularJS, however it doesn't seem to result in the desired behavior.

My form looks like this:

```
<form name="addInviteForm" ng-controller="InviteCtrl" ng-submit="sendInvitation(userEmail)">

      Pristine? {{addInviteForm.$pristine}}

      <!-- email input -->
      <div>
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="userEmail" placeholder="Enter email here"  class="line-item-input see" required>
        <span class="error" ng-show="addInviteForm.email.$error.email" style="color:red">Invalid Email</span>
      </div>

      <!-- submit button -->
      <input type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-success center" value="Send Invitation">
</form>
```

And the corresponding code in my controller:

```
$scope.sendInvitation = function(userEmail) {

        // do some work here ...

        // hmm, this doesn't seem to work ...
        $scope.addInviteForm.$setPristine();
    };
```

Though the form shows that `$pristine` is set to `true` upon form entry, then set to `false` when entering data in the text-box, after submitting the form it does indeed show that `$pristine` is set to true .... and yet the value in the textbox remains as it was before the submit button was pressed.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$setPristine` does not clear values from the controls in the form:

From [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form.FormController):

> Sets the form to its pristine state.
>
> This method can be called to remove the 'ng-dirty' class and set the
>   form to its pristine state (ng-pristine class). This method will also
>   propagate to all the controls contained in this form.
>
> Setting a form back to a pristine state is often useful when we want
>   to 'reuse' a form after saving or resetting it.

As you can see from the above description, `$setPristine` only changes the state of the form (and thereby resets the css applied to each control in the form).

If you want to clear the values of each control, then you need to do for each in code.

[This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/815Bml?p=preview) shows `$setPristine` in action.

Comment: Thank you. Binding `userEmail` to a variable within scope of `InviteCtrl` and resetting that variable upon submission appears to have done the trick.

Comment: Though I will say, the documentation doesn't make that very clear at all. I.e., the semantic distinction between "state" of the control and the current "value" of the control is not at all obvious....