# Clear an input field on form submit in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I've gathered that $setPristine is supposed to do this, but it isn't on my project. This is my form:

```
form(name="new_project", ng-submit="create_project()")
    div.create_wrapper
        input#project_name(required, ng-model="project.name", type="text")
        select#project_language(required, ng-init="project.language='PHP'", ng-model="project.language", ng-options="language for language in languages")
        input.button.tiny.radius(type="submit", value="Create")
```

And the js:

```
$scope.create_project = () ->
    project = new projectFactory this.project
    project.$save project, (form_data) ->
        $scope.projects.push form_data
        $scope.new_project.$setPristine()
```

There are no errors, and pristine is set to true, but the inputs value remains.

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20010290/781707

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Gonna leave this here, since that other question is poorly named for finding the solution to this problem.

You have to manually clear the values of the form elements.

For example, if you have:

```
input#project_name(ng-model="project.name", type="text")
```

To empty it you could do:

```
$scope.project = null
```

in your controller.

Comment: or `delete $scope.project`

Answer (score 0):

You can user your own method but with some improvement. For example,
This is your model into controller:

```
    $scope.registrationForm = {
    'firstName'     : '',
    'lastName'      : ''
};
```

Your HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="registrForm" role="form">
   <input type="text" class="form-control"
                       name="firstName"
                       id="firstName"
                       ng-model="registrationForm.firstName"
                       placeholder="First name"
                       required> First name
   <input type="text" class="form-control"
                       name="lastName"
                       id="lastName"
                       ng-model="registrationForm.lastName"
                       placeholder="Last name"
                       required> Last name
</form
```

Then, you should clone/save your clear state by:

```
$scope.originForm = angular.copy($scope.registrationForm);
```

Your reset function will be:

```
$scope.resetForm = function(){
    $scope.registrationForm = angular.copy($scope.originForm); // Assign clear state to modified form 
    $scope.registrForm.$setPristine(); // this line will update status of your form, but will not clean your data, where `registrForm` - name of form.
};
```

In such way you are able to clean up the whole your form

Comment: Wouldn't you achieve the same thing by using an object to store your form data, but then overwriting it with an empty object when you wanted to clear? That way you don't have to type out a blank version of your object to maintain.

Comment: @Joren, you are right, it's possible to assign an empty object instead of `angular.copy` and a result will be the same